# How to display the URL (from the link) in the search results?

Tags: search, search-results, url, hyperlink, links-list

I've added a simple "Link List".
When I search, the Search Core Result webpart displays a list from all results. But the hyperlink which is generated points to the LinkItem, not to the real URL.

is this possible without using Managed Property as described [here](https://sctxsl.codeplex.com/downloads/get/247836) ?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, your best bet is to use xslt scripts which enable you to modify the search result display of your search query.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SPSE. I'm afraid signatures in answers are generally frowned upon; especially those linking to a commercial site. Please see the [signatures FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 0):

@rfarqleet is correct. I have never done this in such a capacity but here is a good place to start:
[moss-2007-customize-the-search-result-using-xslt-part-3-customize-using-sharepoint-designer-2007](http://zimmergren.net/technical/moss-2007-customize-the-search-result-using-xslt-part-3-customize-using-sharepoint-designer-2007)

More info can be found by googling: "customizing search results using XSLT"